# Creating uuid from cryptographic hash function in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, hash, uuid, bigquery-udf

Given the table below:

| first_name | last_name | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Kennedy | Presidente of USA |
| Elizabeth | Mary | Queen of UK |

I would like to hash the first_name and last_name column and create a UUID for each row.
So I am planning to use a cryptographic hash function, like md5 ou ha1, but I dont know hot to convert it to a UUID format (like: `bc9020e9-df80-5be1-9ee1-ad01f9579649`) using big query.

For cryptographic hash function: `md5(concat(first_name, last_name))`

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION to_uuid(x STRING)
RETURNS STRING
AS (
  concat(substr(to_hex(md5(x)),1,8),
  "-", substr(to_hex(md5(x)),9,4),
  "-", substr(to_hex(md5(x)),13,4),
  "-", substr(to_hex(md5(x)),17,4),
  "-", substr(to_hex(md5(x)),21,12)
  )
);
```